# C++ atof invalid use of void bug

Tags: c++

Please Help I'm so close to finishing this huge project.
I don't understand an error I'm receiving

```
score-=(double)atof(kitty.pop_front());
```

!invalid use of void expression

kitty is a deque type string. Score is a long double. I'm not good with type conversions but the error seems really unrelated?

I tried other forum's solutions but they are all relatively unrelated.

Comment: In addition to the answers given, use `strtof` not `atof`.  `strtof` is better in every way.

Comment: What's wrong with atof()?

Comment: don't use the `(double)` cast. `atof` returns `double` anyway. Using the cast could hide an important error message.

Comment: Thanks to all the people of sovf who answered, the bug was in a function I was not even expecting.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: `atoi` and `atof` do not handle out of range values in a correct way.  `strtol`, `strtof`, `strtod` do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dequeue::pop_front()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/pop_front/) returns void:

```
void pop_front();
```

So you can't use it in an expression that way.

You could instead do:

```
score-=(double)atof(kitty.front().c_str());
kitty.pop_front();
```

Comment: Yes this one worked clear concise; hopefully this is the last bug I encounter. +1 (if I had the reps sorry) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the value in the `deque` is `std::string`, the `atof` function call should be:

```
score -= atof(kitty.front().c_str());
```

The reason is that `atof` expects a `const char*` parameter, and `std::string::c_str()` returns a `const char*` that represents the string.

Second, the `front()` function returns the value that is at the front of the deque.  If you want to remove the value from the `front`, then you call `kitty.pop_front()`.

Comment: Thanks so much for responding, unfortunately I had tried that before but it still yielded the same value. I'll edit to add more of my code but everywhere that happened it gave the same error? If you can help me out just a little bit more, that would make my day.